# An strange bit of code

Tags: cipher

This is a basic cipher. Solve it and tell me what the message says.

Iqsi dub mwtzkrr ixv ubjcao. Kzkf uxvj zv cyfzfr!

Hints will come in time

Comment: Have you seen [Code Puzzles: What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do?r=SearchResults)? It seems pretty applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is rot 123. The resulting message is ``hope you enjoyed the cipher. make sure to upvote!''